# можно ли такое использовать вместо шаблонизатора?

Tags: javascript

```js
let elem = document.createElement('div')

elem.insertAdjacentHTML(`afterbegin`,`...`)
document.body.append(elem)
document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1].remove()
```

Comment: Можно, конечно, если работает. А зачем использовать такое вместо шаблонизатора? В производительности вы вряд ли выиграете - тут такой же синтаксический перебор, только там он вычисляет и преобразует конкретные части документа, а потом выдает все как хтмл, а здесь весь текст трансполируется в хтмл-сущности

Comment: @doox991 я с шаблонизаторами не знаком не использовал и как я понял они создают кусок кода для многократного пользования + дают возможность сгенерировать документ с вычислительными данными так вот думаю накого мне такое если эти 4 строчки тоже сделают это и не надо что то новое подключать

Comment: С шаблонизаторами в любом случае придется рано или поздно познакомиться, потому что это, как правило, требуют. А эти четыре строчки делают то же самое, только с меньшей производительностью, меньшими возможностями и большим неудобством. Если вам не требуются вычисления или шаблоны в хтмл, то зачем вам в принципе генерация средствами жс? А если требуются и вы планируете их реализовывать в строке... не думаю, что потом вы себе спасибо скажете.

Comment: @artomich насчет скорости и требований не знал спасибо а вот на счет возможностей и удобства не соглашусь обратные косые могут использовать вычисление и использовать переменные не думаю что может быть лучше такого максимум на ровне ... спс за коментарий